# Check if a tweet completely done or user close the popup

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am working on a web app using AngularJs as front-end and Laravel as back-end

In many views I have sharing bar with tweet button, I managed to add a share button using twitter javascript widget

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
  'https://dev.twitter.com/',
  document.getElementById('tw'),
  {
    count: 'none',
    text: 'Sharing a URL using the Tweet Button'
  }
).then(function (el) {
  console.log("Button created.", el);
});
```

and also I managed to detect the click event on this twitter share button via

```
twttr.events.bind(
  'tweet',
  function (event) {
    console.log('tweeet', event);
  }
);
```

but this event fires if user clicked on tweet button even if he just closed the popup and didn't tweet !!

I found this thread https://twittercommunity.com/t/need-to-check-if-user-tweet-like-retweet-post-successfully-using-js-intent/61432 on twitter community but it has been since Feb,2015 I hope there is something new after more than one year !

Is there anyway to track a complete successful tweet!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution Peter?

Comment: unfortunately not yet Jasan

Comment: Still looking for the solution